# Verify radio button is clicked or not in cypress

Tags: radio-button, cypress

Can someone help me to check the radio button is clicked or not in cypress. These radio buttons are bootstrap once so there is no change in the class of the radio button.

This is the full element of the radio button:

```
> <input _ngcontent-ixv-c132="" type="radio" formcontrolname="gender"
> value="M" class="form-check-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"
> id="flexRadioM_0" data-testid="g-male-0">
```

I have tried this method to log the radio button status but did not work.

```
 const cb = document.querySelector('[data-testid="g-female"]');
 cy.log(cb.checked)
```

Used below one previously now this one is not working because of the class is not changed according to the click of the radio button,

```
const maleRadioBtn = cy.get('[data-testid="g-male-0"]')
maleRadioBtn.should('have.class', 'mat-radio-button mat-accent mat-radio-checked')
```

Comment: In your DOM, you have `data-testid="g-male-0"` and you try to get `'[data-testid="g-male"]'`

Comment: Yes that is a my mistake but this is not the issue. However I'm editing the post

Answer (score 7):

Do not store the result of a Cypress query, it's potentially going to invalidate if an action causes the DOM to change.

See [Assigning Return Values](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Assigning-Return-Values)

> **Anti-Pattern:**
> Trying to assign the return value of Commands with const, let, or var.

Queries and assertions should be chained like this

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="g-female"]').should('be.checked')
```

or assigned to an alias, which will re-run the query if it gets invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing in variable Use alias because cypress commands are of Asynchronous Nature.

```
cy.get('[data-testid="g-female"]').as('femaleBtn');
cy.get('@femaleBtn).should('be.checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// male button check
const maleButton =  cy.get('[data-testid="g-male"]')
maleButton.should('be.checked')

// Female button check
const femaleButton =  cy.get('[data-testid="g-female"]')
femaleButton.should('be.checked')
```

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution for this one.

```
const femaleBtn =  cy.get('[data-testid="g-female"]')
           femaleBtn.should('be.checked')
```

This worked.